# Does there exist a function analogous to isisomorphic for isodominant graphs?

Tags: matlab, isomorphic

I have two graphs `G1` and `G2`, possibly with colored nodes and edges. Does there exist a function (either MatLab or some other program) that answers the following question:

- Does there exist an isomorphism of `G1`, say `f(G1)`, such that `f(G1)` is greater than or equal to (element-wise dominance)`G2`?

I am aware of the function `isisomorphic` introduced in `R2016B`. This checks answers the question: Given two graphs `G1` and `G2`, possibly with colored nodes and edges, are `G1` and `G2` isomorphic?  One method would be to enumerate all isomorphisms of `G1` and check the above condition.  For larger graphs this seems like it would take too long.

Edit: An answer to this question might be to modify the `isomorphism` function in `MatLab` -- we could replace conditions of the form `f(G1) == G2` with `f(G1) >= G2`.  The `isomorphism` function in the `@graph toolbox` first re-orders the graphs for efficient computation later, then it calls the `isomorphism` function in the `@biograph toolbox`.  This consequently calls the `graphisomorphism` function, which then calls the `Mex` files `graphalgs`, which appears to be a version of the `nauty Trace package`, see [here](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/).  So, in short, it would seem that to answer this question I would need to modify the `nauty package`.